# Which ETL tool do you recommend?

Tags: pentaho, etl, talend, cloveretl

I am using Oracle as a database. We have decided to use another database and need to use ETL tool to transform the data from Oracle to that database.

I have never worked in any ETL tool and also didn't know about it. After doing some web searching, I found some tools like Pentaho, Clover, Talend etc. But, even after reading on these, I am not able to decide which one to use.

Which is the better tool to get start with, easiest to use, and has good performance?

Comment: _I am using Oracle as a database_ seeing this you should opt for OBIEE

Comment: Before you select a tool, you need to identify the nature of the migration (detailed requirements). Shall you use the same schema?, Shall you use all the fields? How about data cleansing? Is the process an on-time or is it an ongoing process? What is the size of the database etc. ETL is not the only tool class, there are tools that strictly focus on data migration.

Comment: AFAIK, yes the schema will be same. Not necessarily all the fields will be used. Basically, we need to keep the two databases(some specific table) in synch.

Answer (score 9):

It's impossible to answer your question without arguing on the migration requirements. Generally speaking, however, the tools your cited are all nice and focus on a particular capabilities set which could help you during the choice:

- Talend: it's eclipse-based; this means that it's really powerful, stable and customizable (creating custom components or even entire eclipse plugins, if you want) and standard (ie. the project structure follows the eclipse stack). It's quite-well embeddable, as it produces java code, but this could be an hassle for the newcomer anyway. The drawback is the learning curve: if you don't manage java at all, your learning curve will be VERY steep, but if you have a java developer in your team, Talend would be a great choice.
- Penthao: it's another well-estabilished solution. Its ETL tool (named Kettle) is just a component of their wider Business Intelligence open platform, which is really good if you need reporting services, OLAP, data mining and so. It's java-based, but the language is completely hidden, so you don't need to be a java developer to use it efficiently. The major drawback is that Kettle is much harder to extend than Talend. This means: poor connectors/components out-of-the-box, few community-made collections. Integration with existing java application would be REALLY a pain in the neck, too!
- CloverETL: I don't use it very often, as it's mostly the younger brothers of the others. Its major advantages are: it's light, easily embeddable and easy to learn. But it's really much less powerful than Talend and even than Kettle.

Comment: You have to consider in Talend DI that constructing customized components requires a proper license and a training by Talend.

Comment: You are right about Pentaho. We are using it on a rather big project, where we found, the limits:
* in Java-Script step there is no code-completion, code-assist. The same applies to the Java step
* arguments vs. parameters
* super hard to dynamically call transformations
* lot more
On the other hand, Pentaho has another tools for OLAP, data mining, reporting. And that is great.

Comment: This is definitively not true. The custom component perspective is available in Talend Open Studio and same is for training material and dacumentation (altough not very well mantained). You don't need a license